# chart.js v 2.0.1 line, scatter chart pointRadius bug or I'm doing it wrong

Tags: chart.js

I can't seem to get pointRadius to work in chart.s v 2, for line or scatter (although pointHoverRadius works fine):
https://jsfiddle.net/norrhult/bqnLysh7/23/

https://jsfiddle.net/norrhult/knqzzd2z/

```
datasets: [
   {
       pointRadius: 15,
       pointHoverRadius: 15,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll work if you use `radius`

```
datasets: [
   {
       radius: 15,
       pointHoverRadius: 15,
       ...
```

Note - looking at the documentation (http://www.chartjs.org/docs) for other chart types (scatter type is not included in the documentation as at the time of writing this answer), this will *probably* be superseded by `pointRadius` (the comments for other chart types suggest that `pointRadius` is preferable and that `radius` works just because the code is currently backward compatible)

---

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9gerc01h/

Comment: Thanks. I saw the documentation, and I thought I had tried radius: xx, but maybe I had it as an option instead of a dataset attribute, or some other screw-up. Scatter is referred to obliquely in the documentation as a chart type or variant of line, although it's not explicitly documented, which would have saved me some time.